# Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML:

```
<button class="sa-button" [ngClass]="'buttonClass'">{{displayText}}</button>
```

The variable I expect to bind to in my typescript file:

```
public buttonClass = "button";
```

The error I get:

> Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

I want to bind a variable which holds the name of the css class I want to apply.

Is there a correct way to do this? I literally copied this out of the angular docs, and it doesn't work.

Comment: If the component under the root module make sure that **BrowserModule** is imported. If it is in a child module import **CommonModule**. These imports being missing will give you that error when trying to use common directives.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642827/cant-bind-to-ngfor-error/40642843#40642843

Comment: JayChase is correct. The Angular docs assume you have all of your components inserted into a single module. So if your app is modularized and you don't have the proper angular module imports, then `ngClass` won't work as expected.

Comment: JayChase's solution doesn't work for me.  CommonModule is imported, still receive the ngClass error.

Answer (score 2):

by adding the single quotes, you are passing in the text in the single quotes.

You want to remove them like so...

```
<button class="sa-button" [ngClass]="buttonClass"  >{{displayText}}</button>
```

Fro more on ngClass, check out the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html)

Comment: I've tried it with and without the quotes

Comment: Single quotes are legit: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Comment: the problem is OP is using a set of single quotes and a set of double quotes. or well they are in the provided code: [ngClass]="'buttonClass'"